# How to convert screen coordinates to control coordinates with embedded form and multiple displays FMX Windows

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I need to know the mouse position with relative coordinates to a ListView control in the `OnItemClickEx` event. In a multidisplay system, it works for the app showing in the primary monitor, but does not work when the app is showing for the secondary or third monitor.

The code to know the mouse position is the following:

```
...
var point : TPointF;
...
point := Screen.MousePos;
point := self.ScreenToClient(point): //we obtain wrong local coordinates for the secondary and third monitor with or without this line 
point := ListView.AbsoluteToLocal(point);
```

What is the correct way to know the mouse cursor coordinates relative to a control (in this use case a `TListView`)?

**UPDATE**

In [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/g76o111eicksykh/Project1.zip?dl=0) example you can see that it works fine in the first Form, but in the embedded form it provides wrong coordinates. It was tested in 10.2 and 10.3 with the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, after doing some research and tests I've found the trick:

```
...
var point : TPointF;
...
  point := Screen.MousePos;
  point := Application.MainForm.ScreenToClient(point); // The calculation should be with the MainForm, not the embedded!!!
  point := ListView.AbsoluteToLocal(point);
```

Comment: That may work for you case because the listview is in the mainform, but it is not a general solution! My answer will work because it applies the ScreenToClient to the form where the listview is embedded.

Comment: François, please see my example in the update section. You can see it works for the TListView in the Form1, but it doesn't work for the TListView in the Form2 when it's embedded in the form1. I'm agree with you that your solution with OnMouseMove it's valid for a general solution, but IMHO the simpler the better and the solution I finally provide it's the correct for the use case with all embedded forms in a 'host' form.

Answer (score 1):

The following code works perfectly with Delphi 10.4.1:

```
procedure TForm1.ListView1ItemClickEx(
    const Sender        : TObject;
    ItemIndex           : Integer;
    const LocalClickPos : TPointF;
    const ItemObject    : TListItemDrawable);
var
    PtScreen   : TPointF;
    PtForm     : TPointF;
    PtListView : TPointF;
begin
    PtScreen   := Screen.MousePos;
    PtForm     := ScreenToClient(PtScreen);
    PtListView := ListView1.AbsoluteToLocal(PtForm);

    Memo1.Lines.Add('ListView1ItemClickEx ' +
                    PtListView.X.ToString + ', ' + PtListView.Y.ToString);
    Memo1.GoToTextEnd;
end;

procedure TForm1.ListView1MouseMove(
    Sender : TObject;
    Shift  : TShiftState;
    X, Y   : Single);
begin
    Memo1.Lines.Add('ListViewMouseMove  ' +
                    X.ToString + ', ' + Y.ToString);
    Memo1.GoToTextEnd;
end;
```

This code will display in a memo the coordinates of the mouse as the mouse cursor moves inside the TListView and show the calculated coordinates from the OnItemClickEx event. Both are the same, on the primary monitor or the secondary monitor.

Maybe you are using an old Delphi version where there was a bug. I don't know. Or the error is elsewhere in your code.

Your issue would be solved if you capture the mouse position from ListView OnMouseMove event handler and save it in variable in your form so that it is readily available from OnItemClickEx event handler:

```
private
    FMouseX : Single;
    FMouseY : Single;


procedure TForm1.ListView1MouseMove(
    Sender : TObject;
    Shift  : TShiftState;
    X, Y   : Single);
begin
    FMouseX := X;
    FMouseY := Y;
end;

procedure TForm1.ListView1ItemClickEx(
    const Sender        : TObject;
    ItemIndex           : Integer;
    const LocalClickPos : TPointF;
    const ItemObject    : TListItemDrawable);
begin
    Memo1.Lines.Add('ListView1ItemClickEx ' +
                    FMouseX.ToString + ', ' + FMouseY.Y.ToString);
    Memo1.GoToTextEnd;
end;
```

Comment: IMHO the OnMouseMove it's not very optimal and there may be a better solution.

Comment: Why do you think it is not optimal? I always use the OnMouseMove method and it never failed.

Comment: I mean in this use case because I suspected that there was a simpler and clean solution. With the solution I've found there is no extra code involved in other events, just only when the user clicks.